# Launch exe file from network location using dynamics CRM plugin

Tags: plugins, exe, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to launch .exe file from network location in dynamics crm plugin using code snippet

```
if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
                Entity account = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                if (account.LogicalName == "account")
                {
                    Process.Start(@"<NetworkLocation>\abcTest.exe");
                }
            }
```

And the snippet throws exception. Any idea how can I launch that .exe from network location.

**Exception**

```
  <ErrorCode>-2147220891</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <d2p1:key>OperationStatus</d2p1:key>
      <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">0</d2p1:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <d2p1:key>SubErrorCode</d2p1:key>
      <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">-2146233088</d2p1:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
  </ErrorDetails>
  <Message>The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password</Message>
  <Timestamp>2016-09-02T04:42:55.1394536Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
```

**Update 1**

It is Dynamics CRM on-premise environment and the file is not on the CRM server.

**Update 2**

Both exe file and CRM are in the same network.

Comment: Have you tried doing 'runas' with user that your CRM app pool runs on? If not then run this on CRM server

Comment: pen, I could not get 'runas'

Comment: what do you mean by that? does any error occured?

Comment: at my local machine it throw same exception but at server machine it do nothing except saving new account

Comment: you used runas on your machine with the same user as on CRM server?

Comment: yes, with same credential I tried